# rtf file contains strange formatting data preventing field merging

Tags: formatting, document, rtf

I created an RTF file using Word 2007.  I want to insert merge fields that can be parsed and merged with database info at a later stage.  The document contained the phrase 'Dear [salutation] [surname] How are you?'.  I then edited the [surname] part to say [lastname].  If I now view the rtf source it contains loads of unwanted characters as follows:

Dear [salutation] [}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af31507 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid6575321 last}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af31507 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid2040086 name}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af31507 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid2434881 ]}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af31507 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid2040086 \r\n\par How are you?

This means that when I try merging then the [lastname] is too mangled to be found for merging.
Does anyone know what's going on here, and how I can prevent Word from embedding all this unwanted stuff?
Thanks.

Comment: IS there a reason you are saving as RTF, and not plain text?

Comment: @mbeckish - I've inherited a system with lots of rtf documents containing field merge chars - I need to stick with the rtf format

Comment: I guess I don't understand your question - why are you asking how to get Word not to insert RTF commands into an RTF document?

Comment: @mbeckish - because I want to use the C# string replace method to replace [lastname] with, say, 'Smith', but the replace function doesn not find [lastname] because it is mangled into the strange character sequence I show in the original post - thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, but the "strange character sequence" in your example is a setof RTF commands.  If it is an RTF file, then you will have to figure out how to parse the file with those commands present.  You can't expect to get Word to save an RTF file with no RTF commands in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I used the System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox to solve the problem, as below:

```
public class RTF
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Merge the merge data with the target RTF document
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="byteStream">Original RTF document</param>
        /// <param name="mergeDatatable">Merge Data (as per sproc_GetDocumentMergeData)</param>
        /// <returns>String representation of the RTF document</returns>
        public static string GetMergedRTFDocument(byte[] byteStream,DataTable mergeDatatable)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox rtb = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteStream);
            rtb.LoadFile(stream, System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText); // Use for RTF

            int selstart = 0;
            string findTerm = "";
            DataRow mergerow = mergeDatatable.Rows[0];
            foreach (DataColumn col in mergeDatatable.Columns)
            {
                findTerm = "[" + col.ColumnName + "]";
                selstart = rtb.Find(findTerm);
                while (selstart > -1)
                {
                    rtb.SelectionStart = selstart;
                    rtb.SelectedText = mergerow[col].ToString();
                    selstart = rtb.Find(findTerm);
                }


            }

            return rtb.Rtf;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular expression expressions to complete this merge process. I have created a blog post about how this can be done.

[Using regular expression to merge database content into Rich Text format template documents](http://tech.humlesite.eu/2017/01/13/using-regular-expression-to-merge-database-content-into-rich-text-format-template-documents/)

An example written in PHP can be found on Github: 
https://github.com/olekrisek/PHP_RTF_RegExMerge